# Enumerating separating subcollections of a set

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, boolean-algebra, combinatorial-designs

Let $S$ be a (finite) set, and let $C \subseteq 2^S$ be a collection of subsets of $S$.  We say that a subcollection $C' \subseteq C$ is *separating* if for any two elements of $S$ there exists a subset in $C'$ that contains exactly one of the two elements.

For example, any collection of cardinality less than $\log_2 \left\lvert S \right\rvert$ cannot be separating, while any collection of cardinality greater than $2^{\left\lvert S \right\rvert - 1}$ is separating.

> Is there an efficient algorithm to construct all separating subcollections given $S$ and $C$?

I am particularly interested in finding separating subcollections of small cardinality.  Perhaps this question is equivalent to some other more well-known problem?

Comment: [OEIS A007600](https://oeis.org/A007600) may have relevant information.

Comment: @BillyJoe Thanks.  However, it seems that their definition of "separating" differs from mine. For one, they require pairs of elements to be separated both ways: i.e., for $x, y \in S$, there exist subsets $C', C''$ such that $C'$ contains $x$ but not $y$, *and* $C''$ contains $y$ but not $x$.  Moreover, they do not restrict the subsets to be from a particular given collection as I have.